# 4 digit capacitor code

Tags: capacitor, markings

In the video, [Let's figure out how to mod the BBC Master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Sgleturods), at [30:35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Sgleturods&t=1825), a polyester capacitor is added to a BBC Micro to provide a colour composite signal (center of photo solder to the legs of two resistors):

[image: Photo of BBC board]

From the schematic, this capacitor (C28) should be 470 pF

[image: Schematic]

However, zooming in to the capacitor on the board, shows a 4 digit code:

[image: Capacitor close up]

The markings are:

```
JAVX
1135
NY
```

This `1135` seems to make little sense and doesn't correspond to any capacitor code that I know of, as these are normally 2 digits or 3 digits (plus a letter). Yes, there is a [4 digit EIA code](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-smd-capacitor-code), but that is for SMD capacitors

I am starting to suspect that the `1135` is a product code and that the *actual value* is printed on the other side, however, I don't have any polyester capacitors to hand to check whether they are printed upon both sides. Can anyone either confirm this suspicion, or determine the capacitor value from the `1135`?

Comment: I would guess that its a date code, the 35th week of 2011, but someone more knowledgable will probably be along soon

Comment: Ah, I suppose that would make sense, so presumably the value *is* on the other side. I had always thought that the printing was just on *one side only*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1135` is the date code. The part is a AVX (now Kyocera/AVX) [CKR04 or CKR05](https://datasheets.kyocera-avx.com/CKR04-08.pdf).

[image]

With the "Military Dash Number" from the other side of the part and the table in the datasheet, you can identify the capacity and voltage rating. For example, 1323 would be a CKR05BX120KS with 10 pF and 200V.

[image]